Why is this integral equal to an elliptic integral?
I'm trying to prove that:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1-2x\cos\left(t\right)}}dt = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}\cos\left(t\right)^{2}}}dt$$
(Note that $x$ is just a parameter with $|x|<1$ here, the integral is w.r.t. $t$). This seems to be true experimentally ( see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nk49kxzimt ). Both integrals have interpretations as average lengths of things on a circle shifted by distance $x$, but I can't seem to see how to make them equal! The RHS is also sometimes called the "complete elliptic integral".

It's certainly not true if $x > 1$, because the integral on the left converges while the one on the right diverges.

Right ya I agree, I only want to show it for $|x|<1$, thanks for noticing that.

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\pi \frac{dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1-2x\cos t}} \\
&= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{2\,dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1-2x\cos(2t)}} & t\to 2t \\
&= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{2\,dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1-2x\left(2\cos^2t-1\right)}} & \text{double angle identity} \\
&= \frac2{\lvert x+1\rvert} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4x}{(x+1)^2} \sin^2 t}} & t\to\frac\pi2-t \\
&= \frac2{\lvert x+1\rvert} K\left(\frac{2\sqrt x}{\lvert x+1\rvert}\right)
\end{align*}$$
which is equivalent to $2K(x)$ under Landen's transformation.
